# Typescript Function Interface with Generic

Tags: typescript

Rewritten:

I've got a function which grabs an object from a database. I want to change the type Record<string, unknown> to a generic.

```
interface GetObjectParams {
  key: string
}

interface GetObject {
  (params: GetObjectParams): Promise<Record<string, unknown> | null>
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const getObjectFromDatabase = (params: GetObjectParams) => ({'text': 'Hello world'});

const getObject: GetObject = async (
  params
) => getObjectFromDatabase(params);

getObject({key: 'some key'});
```

Changed version:

```
interface GetObjectParams {
  key: string
}

interface GetObject {
  <T> (params: GetObjectParams): Promise<T | null>
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const getObjectFromDatabase = (params: GetObjectParams) => ({'text': 'Hello world'});

const getObject: GetObject = async <T> (
  params
) => getObjectFromDatabase(params) as unknown as T;

getObject<SOME TYPE>({key: 'some key'});
```

Here is the changed version, however typescript complains that I have not defined what params is `Parameter 'params' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

[image]

Typescript shuts up when I delcare what params is:

```
const getObject: GetObject = async <T> (
  params: GetObjectParams
) => getObjectFromDatabase(params) as unknown as T;
```

Why do I need to declare params?

Comment: The signature `<T> (a: string, b: string): T` makes very little sense. If I call `test<number>('a', 'b')`, how is the function going to return a number? It can't even know at runtime that it's *supposed* to return a number, because of type erasure.

Comment: My actual function is really long. It's actually just a `getObject(params)` database function. Whereby you pass a generic eg. getObject<Settings> and it should return you a Settings type. I tried to simplify it but I think I might have made it a little more confusing. My question is more about why I lose typing when I explicitly add a generic.

Comment: I'll re-type it with a cutdown version of my function.

Comment: Either way, if the function doesn't accept any argument whose type is related to T, then a return type of T is a "blank cheque". What if I call it like `func<never>(...)`, or `func<ProofOfTheRiemannHypothesis>(...)`?

Comment: Hmm I think I get your point. Would you suggest I simply not use a generic and just typecast it in a separate function?

Comment: Either call it like `func(...) as Thing` instead of `func<thing>(...)`, or add an argument that can be used to either produce/acquire something of type T or verify that the something is of type T (i.e. a type guard function).

Comment: Yep probably a better way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
type Test2 <T>= (a: T, b: T) => T

const test2: Test2<string> = (a, b) => (a + b);

test2('hello', 'world');
```